# write to the default HTML output in SAS EG with a put statement from a data step

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I sometimes want to add some paragraphs to my output in Enterprise Guide or in a stored process to explain the results.

Last century on mainframe, when I was working on mainframe, I just did that with

```
data _null_;
   set remarks;
   file list;
   put remark;
run;
```

I figured out the default html output of SAS EG is called `EGHTML`, but the following

```
data _null_;
   set remarks;
   file EGHTML;
   put remark;
run;
```

gives `ERROR: File is in use, G:\Work\_TD13868_VSRVDCF7055_\#LN00104.`

Is there a way around?

Comment: Have you tried `FILE _WEBOUT`, or `ODS HTML CLOSE` before writing to `EGHTML`, or %STPEND before the step with the put

Comment: Why not use ODS TEXT statements?  Or ODS Report Writing Interface?  https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=odsadvug&docsetTarget=n0w8et93ubh1enn1f34empn5948l.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en